# Images Disappear after one second in gallery slider

Tags: javascript, css, fade

I need in my JS course to make a website with Some requirementsץ
one of them is to make a photo-carrousel by js.

i took an idea from w3bschool.
its work perfect when i use it in empty project but when i use exactly the same code in my site the pictures are dissapearing after one second(only the pictures, the next/prev buttons are fine)

what can be the reason that make it happened?
i tried to changed every single line in the code but still.

```
JS:
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

EDIT:

https://jsfiddle.net/benahr21/5mue1wpd/3/
You can check the code here. i put some random pictures from google here just that you will be able to see. Most of the Pictures are saved in picture gallery in the project so you cant really see how the site look like.
i just wonder about the disappearing pictures.

thanks a lot !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately we can't really help you without seeing the complete code.

Comment: Without knowing details about your site this code doesn't say much. You need to provide additional JS or HTML code to let us see details.

Comment: Better to create an example in fiddle or snippet:https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Edited!take a look:)